# Char pointer doesn't initialize as expected

Tags: c++, pointers, initializer-list, c-str

MyClass.h

```
#pragma once

class MyClass {
public:
    const char* m_var;
    MyClass();
};
```

MyClass.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include "MyClass.h"

MyClass::MyClass() :
    m_var(("Text_" + std::to_string(5)).c_str())
{}
```

Main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "MyClass.h"

int main()
{
    MyClass myClass;
    std::cout << myClass.m_var;
    std::cin.get();
}
```

I was expecting program to output `Text_5`, instead it outputs:

╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠É½÷Y╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠        ╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠⌠       ╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠

Comment: ╠ is 0xCC in codepage 437, and [MSVC fills 0xCC to uninitialized memory to help debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/q/370195/995714). That means you've accessed uninitialized memory. You can find tons of questions about ╠ and 0xCC here on SO

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't do this. Don't attempt to *store* the result of `std::string::c_str()`.

Sub-expression

```
"Text_" + std::to_string(5)
```

produces a *temporary* `std::string` object, which is immediately *automatically destroyed* after the execution of the full expression

```
("Text_" + std::to_string(5)).c_str()
```

When that object is destroyed, C-string `"Text_5"` pointed by `c_str()`'s result is destroyed as well. So, your `m_var` pointer ends up pointing to nowhere. What you see printed is garbage from that "nowhere". The behavior is formally undefined.

For example, this will work "as expected"

```
std::cout << ("Text_" + std::to_string(5)).c_str() << std::endl;
// The temporary is destroyed at the end of the full expression. 
// It lives long enough to make the above output succeed.
```

But this won't

```
const char *str = ("Text_" + std::to_string(5)).c_str();
// The temporary is destroyed at the end of the above expression. 
// Here it is already dead, meaning that `str` is an invalid pointer
// and the output below will not work
std::cout << str << std::endl;
```

And this will work "as expected" again

```
std::string s = "Text_" + std::to_string(5);
const char *str = s.c_str();
// Since `s` is not a temporary, it is not destroyed here, `str` remains 
// valid and the output below works
std::cout << str << std::endl;
```

But in any case, don't try to use the result of `c_str()` for long-term storage. And if you are dealing with temporary objects, don't even think about storing it at all. It is intended to be used only for a moment, preferably within a single expression. If you store the pointer returned by `c_str()`, you risk suddenly discovering that it became invalid without you noticing. Formally it is possible to keep that pointer for a while as long as you really know what you are doing. But what you have above is a schoolbook example of when it fails.